# High power & ethernet over SF/FTP using the cable's shield

Tags: ethernet, poe

I'm working on a custom gigabit high-power POE solution (ideally 200+ watts). Since SF/FTP cable has a lot of shielding, why not use it as a conductor? Using all 4 twisted pairs for DC+ and the shield as DC- should massively increase the current carrying capacity. I know it won't work with any existing POE equipment, that's fine for my application.

Question: Are there any signal integrity downsides to this scheme? I haven't seen anyone else use the shielding in SF/FTP for POE, but that might be because shielded Ethernet cable is not very common for low/medium power devices.

Some background: I'm working on a tethered underwater robot that needs about 300 feet of range. It needs to last a long time without returning to the surface, so I'd rather power it over the tether instead of with batteries. It also needs a data connection, so Ethernet is an obvious choice (and gigabit speeds would be appreciated). Only having one cable going to the robot would be a massive plus, separate data and power cables would be a lot bulkier and harder to manage.

Comment: What cable brand/model, what are the specs for the cable, and how long run of cable, and what voltage would be used? Usually, this is not done, because the cable shield designed to shield, and it is not intended to carry current under normal situations. And a custom solution can't really be called PoE as it won't have any compatibility with standard PoE.

Comment: I was going to use an SF/FTP cable like this - http://hsdlink.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=350 - The braiding on the outside looks like it has similar cross sectional area than the copper conductors, but it's hard to tell

Comment: Sorry but the cable specs are very vague. And your specs too. It really depends if you want to transfer 200W with 1V and 200A, or 200V and 1A, and for how much length (and all the other questions you did not answer yet). And which transformer you are going to use that can pass the current you need through center tap.

Comment: If you are ready to run special cabling and have custom devices at each end, why not just pull both regular AC or DC wiring and regular Ethernet? What are your constraints? Do you actually need Ethernet? at what speed? What distance?

Comment: thanks for the comments, I just added some background. In short, I want to have one cable for power and data, but I don't care about complexity or standards-compliance at each end of the cable